# IBM Watson Speech-to-Text "Recognize audio" method?

Tags: node.js, ibm-cloud, ibm-watson, speech-to-text, ibm-cloud-speech

How is the `recognize` method used to send an audio files to Speech-to-Text for transcription? Where is the audio file accessed? Is there somewhere to put a path to a local file, a Google Storage location, or a download URL?

The [documentation](https://cloud.ibm.com/apidocs/speech-to-text/speech-to-text?code=node#recognize-audio) says:

[image]

OK, that's what I want to do! The documentation says that this is the method:

```js
recognize(params, [callback()])
```

The params I see are:

```js
var params = {
  objectMode: true,
  contentType: 'audio/flac',
  model: 'en-US_BroadbandModel',
  keywords: ['colorado', 'tornado', 'tornadoes'],
  keywordsThreshold: 0.5,
  maxAlternatives: 3
};
```

Is there a parameter for `MediaFileUri`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your link is to the node.js sdk documentation. In which case the audio is sent as the parameter `audio`, which should be either a `NodeJS.ReadableStream` or a `buffer`. You can create a readable stream from a `url` in which case you could add:

```js
params.audio = fs.createReadStream(url);
```

that will require the url to point at an audio file, and not a disguised webpage with an audio player.

Comment: Thanks! Now I see `audio: fs.createReadStream('audio-file2.flac')` in the `params` list.